# Why use overrideProvider or overrideComponent in Angular unit test to change the provider dependency value?

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I have several unit tests that use different values of a dependency property, I read about  overrideProvider and overrideComponent, but I can't think in which case they would be useful when I can just change the value directly without overriding.

For example in the next snippet I'm just reassigning a property in the dependency for each test.

```
describe('TestComponent', () => {
  let component: TestComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestComponent>;

  let testServiceMock: Partial<TestService>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    testServiceMock = {
      someArray: [1, 2, 3]
    };
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [TestComponent],
      providers: [{ provide: TestService, useValue: testServiceMock }]
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

  it('should be true when someArray length is bigger than 1', () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.show).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should be false when someArray is null', () => {
    testServiceMock.someArray = null;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.show).toBeFalsy();
  });
});
```

Here is an stackblitz for more information.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/unit-test-ng-10-natudb?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftest%2Ftest.component.spec.ts